# Marklogic - Restrict property value query to a specific collection

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-dhf

Marklogic version : 9.0-6.2

My requirement is to run a property value query, but restrict to a specific collection. I tried below query hoping that the andQuery would perform intersection on the results, but I am getting back all the documents in the collection "registration".

```
cts.search(
          cts.andQuery[(
            cts.collectionQuery("registration"),
            cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("RegistrationId","reg1"))
            ]
)
```

Also, even if it works with a tweak, it doesn't seem to be an efficient way of getting just one required document (cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery always returns only 1 document in above query). Any suggestions on the best way to restrict cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery to a specific collection?

Comment: Why do you think this query is not a efficient way of getting your document ? MarkLogic is able to use indexes for both constraints (collection and jsonPropertyValue). This should be quite fast ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your query. Try this one ;)

```
cts.search(
  cts.andQuery([
    cts.collectionQuery("registration"),
    cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("RegistrationId","reg1")
  ])
)
```